# How to make some blade templates can be accessed by 1 user but not by another users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-blade

Let say I have 9 blade templates (p1.blade.php until p9.blade.php) and 3 users (member1, member2, and member3)

```
member1 can only access p1.blade.php, p2.blade.php, p3.blade.php
member2 can only access p4.blade.php, p5.blade.php, p6.blade.php
member3 can only access p7.blade.php, p8.blade.php, p9.blade.php
```

How can I do that?

Comment: using policies and `@can` directive

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by access? Ultimately it's you who decide which templates are rendered in your views.

You could selectively some conditional like `@can` or `@if` before an `@include`, or use an `@includeWhen`

[Including sub-views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views)

> If you would like to `@include` a view depending on a given boolean condition, you may use the `@includeWhen` directive:
>
> `@includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])`

For example:

```xml
<ul id="menu">
  @includeWhen($user->role == 'Admin', 'menu.admin', ['data' => $data])
  @includeWhen($user->role == 'Moderator', 'menu.moderator', ['data' => $data])
  @includeWhen($user->role == 'User', 'menu.user', ['data' => $data])
</ul>
```

Checking for roles isn't really the best practice though. Same example with policies

```xml
<ul id="menu">
  @includeWhen($user->can('admin'), 'menu.admin', ['data' => $data])
  @includeWhen($user->can('moderate'), 'menu.moderator', ['data' => $data])
  @includeWhen($user->can('post'), 'menu.user', ['data' => $data])
</ul>
```